# How to build using ant in IBM RAD

Tags: build, websphere, ibm-rad

All,
we have multiple applications that we develop in IBM RAD 7.5.
Since, RAD does build all the applications that are required, I was wondering how can I achieve the same using ant files.

What I wanted to know is apart from my application specific libraries (that I will know where they are etc), which other jar files should my application point to?

I am talking about IBM WAS runtime libraries etc, so that my application builds successfully.
Is there a standard guideline by IBM on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JARs provided in WAS_HOME/dev/ in WebSphere Application Server 7.0 and later, such as was_public.jar or j2ee.jar, are intended specifically for this purpose.

Comment: I see only two jars, was_public.jar and a j2ee.jar for j2ee5 (though there were two more for j2ee 1.3 and j2ee1.4). Is that all I need?

Comment: Yes, those two JARs (was_public.jar + j2ee.jar for whatever version you're intersted in) should have all public WebSphere Application Server APIs needed for compiling.  If for some reason you find an API missing from those JARs, then it would be a product issue that should be reported.

Answer (score 2):

[@bkail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763607/how-to-build-using-ant-in-ibm-rad/7769274#7769274) is probably what you want if you're on one of those more recent versions of WAS (I don't have v7 or v8 installation to verify).

Another option is to expand the Server Runtime library that you have added to your RAD Java Build Path, you'll see the jars you want to include for your Ant build.

However, if you're actually running within RAD, you'll be pointing to a full server runtime which contains more than you need to simply compile. In that case, you can add one of the "WebSphere Application Server vX stub" runtimes just to see which jars those include; they are the minimum for compiling.

Which specific jars are in that environment will depend on your version of WAS, any installed Feature Packs, and probably even Fixpack levels. In many cases - depending on which APIs you're using - all that's needed to compile is `j2ee.jar`.

(You probably already realize this, but remember that you only need those jars in your classpath to compile, you don't want to deploy them in your WAR since they're already part of WAS.)

Comment: +1 for not including the JARs in your WAR WEB-INF/lib.  I've had to debug far too many apps due to this problem...